An enumerative problem in complex numbers
If m = $e^{i\pi/6}$ and n = $e^{i2\pi/3}$, where i is the imaginary unit, be two complex numbers, then number of ordered pair of integers $(p, q)$, $1 \leq p$, $q \leq 100$ which satisfy the equation $n^q=i(m^p)$ is ___
My working: writing $i=e^{i\pi}$ and comparing the exponents yields $4q - p = 3$ whereafter I am unable to proceed. I surmise the equation obtained may be solved using techniques from combinatorics but am not familiar with nor am able to deduce a suitable algorithm.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

If $p = 3+4q$ then $(p,q)=(3+4q,q)$. Both coordinates have to be greater than 1 and less than 100, so we must have $3+4q\leq 100$, or $q\leq 25$, so this would give 25 possibilities. But there are some pairs missing, for example $(p,q)=(1,4)$ is valid but doesn't fit $4q = p +3$, so your deduction of $4q - p =3$ is missing some solutions.

I agree with you that the problem can be reduced onto powers of $m$, the twelfth root of unity. In fact, $i = m^3$ and $n = m^4$.
Thence the given equation $n^q = i(m^p)$ becomes $m^{4q} = n^q = i(m^p) = (m^3)(m^p) = m^{3+p}$.
However this does not imply that $4q = 3+p$, rather we get $4q \equiv 3+p \mod 12$ instead.
Now try to solve that.
First one considers $p\equiv k \mod 12$ for various $1\le k\le 12$ and $1\le p\le 100$.

$k = 1$ results in $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 1, 13, 25, 37, 49, 61, 73, 85, 97$, yielding 9 solutions.
$k = 2$ results in $p\equiv 2 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 2, 14, 26, 38, 50, 62, 74, 86, 98$, yielding 9 solutions.
$k = 3$ results in $p\equiv 3 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 3, 15, 27, 39, 51, 63, 75, 87, 99$, yielding 9 solutions.
$k = 4$ results in $p\equiv 4 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 4, 16, 28, 40, 52, 64, 76, 88, 100$, yielding 9 solutions.
$k = 5$ results in $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 5, 17, 29, 41, 53, 65, 77, 89$, yielding only 8 solutions.
...
$k = 12$ results in $p\equiv 12 \mod 12$, within the given regime one has $p = 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96$, yielding only 8 solutions.

Next one puts these results together.

For $q=1$ one gets $4\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$, with 9 solutions.
The same 9 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 1 \mod 12$, thus providing $9\times 9=81$ solutions here.
For $q=2$ one gets $8\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 2 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 9=72$ solutions here.
For $q=3$ one gets $12\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 9 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 3 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 9=72$ solutions here.
For $q=4$ one gets $16\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$, with 9 solutions.
The same 9 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 4 \mod 12$, thus providing $9\times 9=81$ solutions here.
For $q=5$ one gets $20\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 5 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.
For $q=6$ one gets $24\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 9 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 6 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.
For $q=7$ one gets $28\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$, with 9 solutions.
The same 9 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 7 \mod 12$, thus providing $9\times 8=72$ solutions here.
For $q=8$ one gets $32\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 8 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.
For $q=9$ one gets $36\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 9 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 9 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.
For $q=10$ one gets $40\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 1 \mod 12$, with 9 solutions.
The same 9 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 10 \mod 12$, thus providing $9\times 8=72$ solutions here.
For $q=11$ one gets $44\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 11 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.
For $q=12$ one gets $48\equiv 3+p \mod 12$ or $p\equiv 9 \mod 12$, with 8 solutions.
The same 8 solutions for $p$ would occur however for any $q\equiv 12 \mod 12$, thus providing $8\times 8=64$ solutions here.

Finally note, that all those solution sets are disjunct (because at least the number $q$ differs). Thence the answer would just be their sum.
$81\times 2 + 72\times 4 + 64\times 6 = 834$.
--- rk

Thank you sir, but the workbook wherefrom I source this problem provides the final answer to be 834, without any hint or context. I was wondering how the remaining could be accounted for, or if the answer key might be incorrect.

You are right indeed, case $q=2$ was erroniously dubbt to be $8\times 8$, but $p\equiv 5 \mod 12$ clearly provides 8, but $q\equiv 2 \mod 12$ rather provides 9, thus it ought be $8\times 9$ there (now corrected), which exactly accounts for the missing 8 solutions, you mentioned. Sorry.
